# Alert me when INDEX MATCH returns multiple results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using an INDEX MATCH formula to pull "Store Address" based on "Store Number"

However, sometimes there are multiple "Store Addresses" for a single "Store Number". In this case, the user needs to investigate which store address to use.

`=INDEX("Store Numbers",MATCH("Given Store Address","All Store Addresses",0))`

Is it possible for me to know that there are multiple Store Addresses for a specific Store Number? I.e. some kind of alert?

Please Note: My goal is not to return multiple values. My goal is to somehow know when there are multiple values so that the user can investigate further.

Many thanks.

Comment: conditional formatting on the range of adresses and as formula `COUNTIF` i would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

put `=INDEX("Store Numbers",MATCH("Given Store Address","All Store Addresses",0))` in one cell and `=IF(COUNTIF("All Store Addresses","Given Store Address")>1,"MoreThanOne","")` in the cell next to it..

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can count all not empty cells and subtract all [unique cells](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif) with

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A10,"<>"&"")-SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10<>"")/COUNTIF(A2:A10,A2:A10&""))
```

to get the number of not unique cells.
To see which record is a duplicate, put in `B2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,A2)>1,"yes","no")
```

Adapt the ranges to your needs. You can use the condition-part of the `IF` in the last formula in conditional formatting.

[image]